# How to get distinct values for some certain keys from a list of dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am facing an issue while selecting distinct  values for some keys.
Scenario: My code call a table in sql server thru the odbc driver. The sql table has say 10 columns and i query all 10 columns through 1 call. But in my code I don't need to use 10 columns at once, I need say 5 columns at one time and their distinct value. I can do that by another db call but I want to avoid multiple db calls. Any python way to solve this?
Example:

```
my_list = [{'workflow_id':1,'file':'aaa','table':'table1','order':1},
           {'workflow_id':1,'file':'aaa','table':'table1','order':2},
           {'workflow_id':1,'file':'aaa','table':'table2','order':1},
           {'workflow_id':1,'file':'aaa','table':'table2','order':2}]

# Expecting below output
my_new_list = [{'workflow_id':1,'file':'aaa','table':'table1'},
               {'workflow_id':1,'file':'aaa','table':'table2'}]
```

Comment: Consider this: the database would be faster at this than Python. Multiple calls to a database have their upside too.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT DISTINCT column FROM table`

See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: Thanks! I know the SQL way to do. Just seeing if it is doable in a pythonic way avoiding multiple db calls. @kris

Comment: [https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) - "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." Database calls are not as heavy as you think, especially at low levels.

Answer (score 0):

For the given input:

```
my_list = [{'workflow_id':1,'file':'aaa','table':'table1','order':1},
           {'workflow_id':1,'file':'aaa','table':'table1','order':2},
           {'workflow_id':1,'file':'aaa','table':'table2','order':1},
           {'workflow_id':1,'file':'aaa','table':'table2','order':2}]
```

Here is a Python way to do it:

```
import copy

def remove_order(data):
    result = copy.deepcopy(data)
    for entry in result:
        if 'order' in entry:
            del entry['order']
    return result

def remove_duplicates(data):
    result = list()
    for entry in data:
        if entry not in result:
            result.append(entry)
    return result

my_new_list = remove_duplicates(remove_order(my_list))

print my_new_list
```

Here is the output:

```
[{'table': 'table1', 'workflow_id': 1, 'file': 'aaa'}, 
 {'table': 'table2', 'workflow_id': 1, 'file': 'aaa'}]
```

Note the use of deepcopy in case it is important to maintain the contents of the original list.